# Find the source code of the package installed in a particular anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, source-code

I want to find the source code of the matplotlib package installed in an anaconda environment 'blah'. This 'blah' environment is a near copy of the anaconda base environment but has numpy, scipy, matplotlib installed.

Answer (score 0):

Say we want to find the source code of the [qutip](http://qutip.org/) package installed in an 
   anaconda environment 'qutip-env'. 
   Your python version is 3.6. Typing the following command in the terminal will take you there.

> cd ~/anaconda3/envs/qutip-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qutip

A simple 'ls' will reveal the contents of this folder. This is the source code of the 'qutip'
   package